# how to validate dijit radiobutton?

Tags: forms, validation, dojo

I have a set of dijit.form.RadioButton elements. I need to be this set as mandatory. When submitting the form it should stop if no radio button is selected. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form's onSubmit function, check to see if the radio buttons value is null or not:

```
if (this.attr("value").radio)
```

It's true if set to the value of one of the radios, false if null (no radio is selected).  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbumpusbarnett/N2fcT/) is a full example.